# Adjust divs in div

Tags: css, xhtml

I have a div and 5 divs in it.

```
<div style="width: 1000px">
 <div style="float: left; width: 50px;"></div>
 <div style="float: left; width: 50px;"></div>
 <div style="float: left; width: 50px;"></div>
 <div style="float: left; width: 50px;"></div>
 <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Now i want to adjust the inner divs to the right.

Comment: "Adjust to the right" as in float:right?

Comment: float:right to all will solve the problem I guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving the parent div a padding-left, as such:

```
<div style="width: 1000px;padding-left:100px">
 <div style="float: left; width: 50px;"></div>
```

Or you can try positioning each element by their own, with margin-left:

```
<div style="width: 1000px;">
 <div style="float: left; width: 50px;margin-left:100px"></div>
```

Some resources:

```
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp
```

Comment: Is there any way to adjust them dynamicly? Because the count of inner divs is not static.

Comment: @elairoo How do you mean? If padding is applied to the parent div, then there will always be a static space between the parent and the child/ren (Just like there is a tiny space between the characters I now write and the box I write in). 

If you on the other hand would apply the margin, then the spacing would be dynamic (Just like there is space between the words here, the space would be relative to the child/ren).

Comment: The best way to to this, however you choose to do it, is to apply a _italic_class_italic_ to your inner elements, and then simply style the class (Like this: #some-div .someClass { //styling }, if you assign your inner divs to the .someClass, then the styling will be consistent throughout all your inner divs )

Comment: [w3schools](http://w3fools.com/) frequently publishes [inaccurate or misleading](http://w3fools.com/) content. It is harmful to the web.  Developers deserve better information sources. Try [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Give the parent div a `padding-left: 50px` insert whatever size you want.

If you want them centered, put them in another div, and center that div inside the original parent.